# Debugging an emacs font configuration problem on OS X

Tags: fonts

Often when I'm editing a file with many uncommon unicode symbols (e.g., in languages like haskell, julia or c++), and (I think) especially with an ornate color theme, I experience delays of maybe about five seconds when switching between buffers. Running emacs under lldb show a stack trace below; I get a similar stack trace from running `emacs -Q` and typing `C-h h` (`view-hello-file`), which takes quite a while to display the hello file.

What can I do about these window redrawing delays? I am not sure what I have misconfigured.

Does emacs reload all fonts every time I switch to a different frame or buffer? It also seems to have a delay sometimes when a previously invisible overlay is shown.

Also related is that `fontd` CPU usage spikes during the delay.

I'm using `OS X 10.9.5` with emacs compiled from source

```
GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS apple-appkit-1265.21)
```

but I've had this problem with git development version as well some time ago.

Stack trace from `-Q`. This is similar to the one below from regular emacs use, so I suspect the slowness of `view-hello-file` is related.

```
* thread #1: tid = 0xfc87d, 0x00007fff86f26a1a libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff86f26a1a libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff86f25d18 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 64
    frame #2: 0x00007fff91f0c78d libFontRegistry.dylib`XTSendCopyPropertyForFonts + 227
    frame #3: 0x00007fff91f2987c libFontRegistry.dylib`TGlobalFontRegistryImp::CopyPropertyForFonts(__CFArray const*, __CFString const*, TFontQueryOptions const&) const + 292
    frame #4: 0x00007fff91f0c16f libFontRegistry.dylib`XTCopyPropertyForFonts + 115
    frame #5: 0x00007fff86e20817 CoreText`TBaseFont::CreateTraitsValuesPerFontInfo() const + 143
    frame #6: 0x00007fff86e2068f CoreText`TBaseFont::CopyTraitsInternal() const + 87
    frame #7: 0x00007fff86e22e81 CoreText`TBaseFont::CreateTraitsValues() const + 29
    frame #8: 0x00007fff86e22e49 CoreText`TBaseFont::GetSymbolicTraitsInternal() const + 21
    frame #9: 0x00007fff86e22e17 CoreText`TBaseFont::GetSymbolicTraits(bool) const + 17
    frame #10: 0x00007fff86e7fe63 CoreText`CompareLocalizedDescriptorsByTraitsAndPrecedence(void const*, void const*, void*, bool, bool) + 353
    frame #11: 0x00007fff92040547 CoreFoundation`__CFSimpleMergeSort + 455
    frame #12: 0x00007fff9204034b CoreFoundation`CFSortIndexes + 443
    frame #13: 0x00007fff92040048 CoreFoundation`CFQSortArray + 232
    frame #14: 0x00007fff9203fefe CoreFoundation`CFArraySortValues + 1054
    frame #15: 0x00007fff86e7f008 CoreText`TDescriptorSource::CopyAllDescriptorsInternal(bool, CFComparisonResult (*)(void const*, void const*, void*)) const + 186
    frame #16: 0x00007fff86e7f142 CoreText`TDescriptorSource::CopyAllDescriptorsSorted() const + 26
    frame #17: 0x00007fff86e25bfd CoreText`TDescriptor::CreateMatchingDescriptors(__CFSet const*, unsigned long) const + 249
    frame #18: 0x00007fff86e6bf36 CoreText`CTFontDescriptorCreateMatchingFontDescriptors + 87
    frame #19: 0x00007fff8b55c521 AppKit`-[NSCTFontDescriptor matchingFontDescriptorsWithMandatoryKeys:] + 12
    frame #20: 0x00000001001c5d60 Emacs`ns_findfonts(font_spec=4345331237, isMatch='\0') + 1600 at nsfont.m:564
    frame #21: 0x000000010014ab10 Emacs`font_list_entities(f=0x000000010282b648, spec=4330619989) + 720 at font.c:2759
    frame #22: 0x000000010014cc33 Emacs`font_find_for_lface(f=0x000000010282b648, attrs=0x00000001077b2780, spec=<unavailable>, c=-1) + 1971 at font.c:3235
    frame #23: 0x00000001001985bb Emacs`fontset_find_font(fontset=4329826901, c=3626, face=0x00000001077b2780, id=<unavailable>, fallback=false) + 1755 at fontset.c:636
    frame #24: 0x0000000100194f13 Emacs`fontset_font(fontset=4339946117, c=3626, face=0x00000001077b2780, id=38) + 323 at fontset.c:754
    frame #25: 0x0000000100194d41 Emacs`face_for_char(f=0x000000010282b648, face=0x00000001077b2780, c=3626, pos=<unavailable>, object=<unavailable>) + 337 at fontset.c:956
    frame #26: 0x000000010001b19b Emacs`get_next_display_element(it=<unavailable>) + 2907 at xdisp.c:7193
    frame #27: 0x00000001000284d8 Emacs`display_line(it=0x00007fff5fbf76c8) + 1304 at xdisp.c:20183
    frame #28: 0x0000000100027de6 Emacs`try_window(window=<unavailable>, flags=1, pos=<unavailable>) + 214 at xdisp.c:16972
    frame #29: 0x000000010004bb43 Emacs`redisplay_window(window=4337071693, just_this_one_p=false) + 13651 at xdisp.c:16451
    frame #30: 0x00000001000524f6 Emacs`redisplay_window_0(window=<unavailable>) + 38 at xdisp.c:14348
    frame #31: 0x0000000100138b34 Emacs`internal_condition_case_1(bfun=0x00000001000524d0, arg=4337071693, handlers=<unavailable>, hfun=<unavailable>) + 260 at eval.c:1372
    frame #32: 0x0000000100048554 Emacs`redisplay_windows(window=<unavailable>) + 180 at xdisp.c:14328
    frame #33: 0x0000000100048512 Emacs`redisplay_windows(window=<unavailable>) + 114 at xdisp.c:14322
    frame #34: 0x0000000100026938 Emacs`redisplay_internal + 6184 at xdisp.c:13927
    frame #35: 0x00000001000c1a5e Emacs`read_char(commandflag=1, map=4329109910, prev_event=4328534074, used_mouse_menu=0x00007fff5fbff31f, end_time=0x0000000000000000) + 1982 at keyboard.c:2570
    frame #36: 0x00000001000bf0dc Emacs`read_key_sequence(bufsize=<unavailable>, keybuf=<unavailable>, prompt=<unavailable>, dont_downcase_last=<unavailable>, can_return_switch_frame=<unavailable>, fix_current_buffer=<unavailable>, prevent_redisplay=<unavailable>) + 1964 at keyboard.c:9088
    frame #37: 0x00000001000be6f0 Emacs`command_loop_1 + 4736 at keyboard.c:1452
    frame #38: 0x0000000100138a1b Emacs`internal_condition_case(bfun=0x00000001000bd470, handlers=<unavailable>, hfun=<unavailable>) + 251 at eval.c:1348
    frame #39: 0x00000001000ceb6e Emacs`command_loop_2(ignore=<unavailable>) + 62 at keyboard.c:1177
    frame #40: 0x00000001001383a3 Emacs`internal_catch(tag=<unavailable>, func=0x00000001000ceb30, arg=4328534074) + 243 at eval.c:1112
    frame #41: 0x00000001000bcaad Emacs`recursive_edit_1 [inlined] command_loop + 68 at keyboard.c:1156
    frame #42: 0x00000001000bca69 Emacs`recursive_edit_1 + 265 at keyboard.c:777
    frame #43: 0x00000001000bcbf2 Emacs`Frecursive_edit + 242 at keyboard.c:848
    frame #44: 0x00000001000bb7da Emacs`main(argc=0, argv=<unavailable>) + 5850 at emacs.c:1646
```

Stack trace from regular emacs use:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0xd3a52, 0x00007fff86f2a5da libsystem_kernel.dylib`__open + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff86f2a5da libsystem_kernel.dylib`__open + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff8c6ec4f7 libFontParser.dylib`TFileDescriptorContext::TFileDescriptorContext(char const*) + 67
    frame #2: 0x00007fff8c6ec2f5 libFontParser.dylib`TFileDataReference::TFileDataReference(char const*) + 117
    frame #3: 0x00007fff8c6ec0fc libFontParser.dylib`TFileDataSurrogate::TFileDataSurrogate(char const*, bool) + 142
    frame #4: 0x00007fff8c6eaa3b libFontParser.dylib`TFont::CreateFontEntitiesForFile(char const*, bool, TSimpleArray<TFont*>&, bool, short, char const*) + 1847
    frame #5: 0x00007fff8c6e9e1f libFontParser.dylib`FPFontCreateFontsWithPath + 253
    frame #6: 0x00007fff9190b1f4 libCGXType.A.dylib`create_private_data_with_path + 19
    frame #7: 0x00007fff8df42185 CoreGraphics`CGFontCreateFontsWithPath + 40
    frame #8: 0x00007fff8df41d9a CoreGraphics`CGFontCreateFontsWithURL + 383
    frame #9: 0x00007fff86e0f2ec CoreText`CreateFontWithFontURL(__CFURL const*, bool) + 60
    frame #10: 0x00007fff86e0f10b CoreText`TCGFontCache::CopyFont(__CFURL const*, bool) const + 91
    frame #11: 0x00007fff86e0ef35 CoreText`TBaseFont::CopyNativeFont() const + 69
    frame #12: 0x00007fff86e0eeb6 CoreText`TBaseFont::CopyGraphicsFont() const + 26
    frame #13: 0x00007fff86e14a6b CoreText`TBaseFont::CopyAvailableTables(unsigned int) const + 31
    frame #14: 0x00007fff86e1471b CoreText`TBaseFont::GetFormat() const + 249
    frame #15: 0x00007fff86e7713b CoreText`TBaseFont::CopyFormat() const + 21
    frame #16: 0x00007fff86e2039a CoreText`TBaseFont::CopyAttribute(unsigned long) const + 874
    frame #17: 0x00007fff86e0e291 CoreText`TDescriptor::CopyAttribute(__CFString const*) const + 175
    frame #18: 0x00007fff86e0e1bf CoreText`CTFontDescriptorCopyAttribute + 99
    frame #19: 0x00000001001c6f1a Emacs`macfont_list(f=<unavailable>, spec=4345331237) + 2986 at macfont.m:2313
    frame #20: 0x000000010014ab10 Emacs`font_list_entities(f=0x000000010104f248, spec=4782535053) + 720 at font.c:2759
    frame #21: 0x000000010014cc33 Emacs`font_find_for_lface(f=0x000000010104f248, attrs=0x000000010d1adb60, spec=<unavailable>, c=949) + 1971 at font.c:3235
    frame #22: 0x0000000100198711 Emacs`fontset_find_font(fontset=4325821517, c=<unavailable>, face=0x000000010d1adb60, id=<unavailable>, fallback=false) + 2097 at fontset.c:681
    frame #23: 0x0000000100194f13 Emacs`fontset_font(fontset=4440753229, c=949, face=0x000000010d1adb60, id=-1) + 323 at fontset.c:754
    frame #24: 0x0000000100194d41 Emacs`face_for_char(f=0x000000010104f248, face=0x000000010d1adb60, c=949, pos=<unavailable>, object=<unavailable>) + 337 at fontset.c:956
    frame #25: 0x000000010001b19b Emacs`get_next_display_element(it=<unavailable>) + 2907 at xdisp.c:7193
    frame #26: 0x000000010002d4cf Emacs`display_string(string=<unavailable>, lisp_string=<unavailable>, face_string=<unavailable>, face_string_pos=<unavailable>, start=<unavailable>, it=0x00007fff5fbf7678, field_width=<unavailable>, precision=<unavailable>, max_x=<unavailable>, multibyte=<unavailable>) + 1599 at xdisp.c:23391
    frame #27: 0x00000001000303fb Emacs`display_mode_element(it=0x00007fff5fbf7678, depth=<unavailable>, field_width=<unavailable>, precision=<unavailable>, elt=<unavailable>, props=<unavailable>, risky=1) + 9115 at xdisp.c:21980
    frame #28: 0x000000010002e428 Emacs`display_mode_element(it=<unavailable>, depth=<unavailable>, field_width=<unavailable>, precision=<unavailable>, elt=<unavailable>, props=4328534074, risky=1) + 968 at xdisp.c:22274
    frame #29: 0x000000010002e428 Emacs`display_mode_element(it=<unavailable>, depth=<unavailable>, field_width=<unavailable>, precision=<unavailable>, elt=<unavailable>, props=4328534074, risky=1) + 968 at xdisp.c:22274
    frame #30: 0x0000000100019df2 Emacs`display_mode_line(w=<unavailable>, face_id=MODE_LINE_FACE_ID, format=4322675206) + 402 at xdisp.c:21791
    frame #31: 0x0000000100050ac7 Emacs`display_mode_lines(w=0x0000000101046248) + 359 at xdisp.c:21734
    frame #32: 0x0000000100049c1a Emacs`redisplay_window(window=4312031821, just_this_one_p=false) + 5674 at xdisp.c:16804
    frame #33: 0x00000001000524f6 Emacs`redisplay_window_0(window=<unavailable>) + 38 at xdisp.c:14348
    frame #34: 0x0000000100138b34 Emacs`internal_condition_case_1(bfun=0x00000001000524d0, arg=4312031821, handlers=<unavailable>, hfun=<unavailable>) + 260 at eval.c:1372
    frame #35: 0x0000000100048554 Emacs`redisplay_windows(window=<unavailable>) + 180 at xdisp.c:14328
    frame #36: 0x0000000100048512 Emacs`redisplay_windows(window=<unavailable>) + 114 at xdisp.c:14322
    frame #37: 0x0000000100026938 Emacs`redisplay_internal + 6184 at xdisp.c:13927
    frame #38: 0x00000001000c1a5e Emacs`read_char(commandflag=1, map=4326491702, prev_event=4328534074, used_mouse_menu=0x00007fff5fbff31f, end_time=0x0000000000000000) + 1982 at keyboard.c:2570
    frame #39: 0x00000001000bf0dc Emacs`read_key_sequence(bufsize=<unavailable>, keybuf=<unavailable>, prompt=<unavailable>, dont_downcase_last=<unavailable>, can_return_switch_frame=<unavailable>, fix_current_buffer=<unavailable>, prevent_redisplay=<unavailable>) + 1964 at keyboard.c:9088
    frame #40: 0x00000001000be6f0 Emacs`command_loop_1 + 4736 at keyboard.c:1452
    frame #41: 0x0000000100138a1b Emacs`internal_condition_case(bfun=0x00000001000bd470, handlers=<unavailable>, hfun=<unavailable>) + 251 at eval.c:1348
    frame #42: 0x00000001000ceb6e Emacs`command_loop_2(ignore=<unavailable>) + 62 at keyboard.c:1177
    frame #43: 0x00000001001383a3 Emacs`internal_catch(tag=<unavailable>, func=0x00000001000ceb30, arg=4328534074) + 243 at eval.c:1112
    frame #44: 0x00000001000bcaad Emacs`recursive_edit_1 [inlined] command_loop + 68 at keyboard.c:1156
    frame #45: 0x00000001000bca69 Emacs`recursive_edit_1 + 265 at keyboard.c:777
    frame #46: 0x00000001000bcbf2 Emacs`Frecursive_edit + 242 at keyboard.c:848
    frame #47: 0x00000001000bb7da Emacs`main(argc=0, argv=<unavailable>) + 5850 at emacs.c:1646
```

Comment: Do you also see CPU usage spikes from `fontd` whenever you experience a delay?

Comment: @lunaryorn Yes, I do. I'm not seeing any corrupt fonts, though.

Comment: Nor do I, and I occasionally see this issue as well.  I haven't yet bothered to debug it, though, I was just curious whether we have the same issue.  Did you `M-x report-emacs-bug`?

Comment: @lunaryorn No, I didn't report this. While it's a problem, I'm not really sure this is an *emacs* bug. I'm a bit surprised emacs spends so much time looking for fonts (shouldn't there be a cache for this? Is there a cache in CoreText? I haven't understood the code yet).

Comment: @lunaryorn Bug report [here](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=19266), can you add anything?

Comment: No, I can't.  In fact, you've gone way farther than I to isolate and debug it.  I've never suffered from it so badly, and was able to get rid of most of the delays by removing special symbols from my mode line setup.

Comment: The replies in the bug report about “optimizing the font configuration” made me think that the [unicode-fonts](https://github.com/rolandwalker/unicode-fonts) package could help.  Does the delay vanish/decrease if you install and setup that package?  As far as I understand it, it adds explicit mappings from unicode characters to fonts, which could prevent Emacs from the lengthy search for good fonts which causes the noticable delays.